# Image Android Phone, then run on Windows

Tags: backup, restore, android-emulator, bluestacks, factory-image

Is there any way to take an image of an android device, then run that image on an Android emulator (e.g. BlueStacks) in Windows?

I'd like to do this as a way to help investigate an issue with some Android software (specifically, a rollout of a Soti MobiControl upgrade which worked on most devices, but erred on a subset with common features (OS version & hardware):

- I have a device on which I can reproduce the behaviour, which I'd like to take an image / backup of before doing a factory reset on the phone to see if the issue reoccurs after a clean install.
- I'd then use the image / backup to restore the phone to its faulty state if the factory reset resolved the issue, so we could zero in on the root cause (i.e. to find a more efficient fix before pushing this out to all phones).
- If I could emulate the faulty device, I could also check whether the emulated version still had the issue, and if so try upgrading the version of Android on the emulator beyond what the device's hardware supports to see if that's the issue.

i.e. this gives me lots of options, some of which are mentioned above.

Comment: Hardware layer is gonna be impossible to emulate - it's just like trying to run a ROM for one device on another.

Comment: Agreed.  My thinking is if the issue is reproducible on the emulated image that suggests that it's something to do with the OS version or something else in that image.  If it's not reproducable, that points at / implies something lower level; e.g. the hardware or something very low level in the OS.  The idea's just to have a way to narrow down possible causes quickly; and if reproducible, have another toolkit we can use to investigate the issue.